# call a method from .aspx .cs to .aspx

Tags: asp.net, .aspxauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asp.net codebehind from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136274/asp-net-codebehind-from-javascript)

Expert.please give me an example for calling a function (method)inside .aspx page which is written in .aspx.cs page .please use javascript for calling that function..give me full code then only it will really helpful for me...

Answer (score 0):

See this:

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

see http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2 for that... You could have done beeter then me if you google it out...